# How to style radio button labels in VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, css, styleclass

I am having a lot of trouble styling the radio button labels in my page.

In the image below you can see that the style of the radio button labels is completely wrong - they should all be the same as the greeen circled section, which is defined as `MainPanelFont`:

[image]

```
<table border="" class="WizardTable" align="left" style="width:30%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1 1em;" >        
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div  class="MainPanelFont">
                Please select the frequency<br/> for the data request:    
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:33%; padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" colspan="2">
            <div class="Mandatory">
                <apex:selectRadio styleClass="MainPanelFont" layout="pageDirection" value="{!sObjectRFC.Frequency__c}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!FrequencyOptions}"/>    
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </div>  
        </td>                                                        
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is the way the style class `MainPanelFont` is defined:

```
*[class~="Grey"],
*[class~="MainPanelFont"],
a.MainPanelFont,
span.MainPanelFont,
.country-name,
.dial-code{
    color:#666c71; 
    font-family : Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size : 13px
}
```

so what do I need to do in my page to have the radio button labels styled the same as the other sections?

Comment: try `border-radius` it will solve the problem.

Comment: this might [help](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found the solution is to embrace the fact that a VF/Apex `<selectRadio>` tage creates a table with labels and `<input type="radio" ...` option buttons:

So I created a style in my page called `radioOpt`:

```
<style>        
    .radioOpt td, .radioOptinput, .radioOpt label{
    color:#666c71; 
    font-family : Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size : 13px   
    }     
</style>
```

and applied it to the VF `selectRadio` table as below:

```
<table border="" class="WizardTable radioOpt" align="left" style="width:30%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1 1em;" >        
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div  class="MainPanelFont">
                Please select the frequency<br/> for the data request:    
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:33%; padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" colspan="2">
            <div class="Mandatory">
                <apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioOpt" layout="pageDirection" value="{!sObjectRFC.Frequency__c}" id="outMailshot_Frequency__c">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!FrequencyOptions}"/>    
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </div>  
        </td>                                                        
    </tr>
</table>
```

this now renders the radio button labels with the correct formatting as below:

[image]

But it's a shame that we need to jump through hoops like this, and that when rendering the HTML VF doesn't inherit the formatting of the containing object